# Problema al subir archivos a OwnCloud

Tags: fileupload, nextcloud

Hola amigos tengo un problema al cargar archivos en `OwnCloud` este lo e instalado con `Softaculous` de `cPanel` pero no me deja cargar los archivos solo se queda en espere unos segundos y no pasa nada, viendo el log en `Chrome` aparece este error:

> jquery.js:8630 PUT
>   http://nombre.dominio.com/owncloud/remote.php/webdav/Documents/archivo.png
>
> 403 (Forbidden) send @ jquery.js:8630 ajax @ jquery.js:8166 send @
>   jquery.fileupload.js?v=a9e1a600d8a15933c86dcad2284676cf:906
>   (anonymous) @ jquery.js:3256 j @ jquery.js:3099 add @ jquery.js:3145
>   (anonymous) @ jquery.js:3255 each @ jquery.js:374 (anonymous) @
>   jquery.js:3252 a.Deferred @
>   jquery-migrate.min.js?v=a9e1a600d8a15933c86dcad2284676cf:2 then @
>   jquery.js:3251
>   _onSend @ jquery.fileupload.js?v=a9e1a600d8a15933c86dcad2284676cf:950 (anonymous) @
>   jquery-ui.custom.js?v=a9e1a600d8a15933c86dcad2284676cf:405 data.submit
>   @ jquery.fileupload.js?v=a9e1a600d8a15933c86dcad2284676cf:674
>   (anonymous) @ file-upload.js?v=a9e1a600d8a15933c86dcad2284676cf:274
>   (anonymous) @ jquery.js:3256 j @ jquery.js:3099 add @ jquery.js:3145
>   (anonymous) @ jquery.js:3255 each @ jquery.js:374 (anonymous) @
>   jquery.js:3252 a.Deferred @
>   jquery-migrate.min.js?v=a9e1a600d8a15933c86dcad2284676cf:2 then @
>   jquery.js:3251 submit @
>   file-upload.js?v=a9e1a600d8a15933c86dcad2284676cf:273 (anonymous) @
>   file-upload.js?v=a9e1a600d8a15933c86dcad2284676cf:582
>   *.each.*.forEach @ underscore.js?v=a9e1a600d8a15933c86dcad2284676cf:153 submitUploads @
>   file-upload.js?v=a9e1a600d8a15933c86dcad2284676cf:580 onNoConflicts @
>   file-upload.js?v=a9e1a600d8a15933c86dcad2284676cf:1013
>   checkExistingFiles @
>   file-upload.js?v=a9e1a600d8a15933c86dcad2284676cf:790 add @
>   file-upload.js?v=a9e1a600d8a15933c86dcad2284676cf:1035
>   _trigger @ jquery-ui.custom.js?v=a9e1a600d8a15933c86dcad2284676cf:789 (anonymous) @
>   jquery.fileupload.js?v=a9e1a600d8a15933c86dcad2284676cf:1037 each @
>   jquery.js:374
>   _onAdd @ jquery.fileupload.js?v=a9e1a600d8a15933c86dcad2284676cf:1030 (anonymous) @
>   jquery-ui.custom.js?v=a9e1a600d8a15933c86dcad2284676cf:405 (anonymous)
>   @ jquery.fileupload.js?v=a9e1a600d8a15933c86dcad2284676cf:1236 j @
>   jquery.js:3099 add @ jquery.js:3145 always @ jquery.js:3246
>   _onChange @ jquery.fileupload.js?v=a9e1a600d8a15933c86dcad2284676cf:1226
>   (anonymous) @
>   jquery-ui.custom.js?v=a9e1a600d8a15933c86dcad2284676cf:405
>   handlerProxy @
>   jquery-ui.custom.js?v=a9e1a600d8a15933c86dcad2284676cf:706 dispatch @
>   jquery.js:4435 r.handle @ jquery.js:4121
>   file-upload.js?v=a9e1a600d8a15933c86dcad2284676cf:354 Uncaught
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'documentElement' of undefined
>       at OC.FileUpload.getResponse (file-upload.js?v=a9e1a600d8a15933c86dcad2284676cf:354)
>       at HTMLInputElement.fail (file-upload.js?v=a9e1a600d8a15933c86dcad2284676cf:1081)
>       at $.(/owncloud/index.php/apps/files/anonymous function).(anonymous function)._trigger
>   (http://demo1.dominio.com/owncloud/core/vendor/jquery-ui/ui/jquery-ui.custom.js?v=a9e1a600d8a15933c86dcad2284676cf:789:13)
>       at $.(/owncloud/index.php/apps/files/anonymous function).(anonymous function)._onFail
>   (http://demo1.dominio.com/owncloud/apps/files/js/jquery.fileupload.js?v=a9e1a600d8a15933c86dcad2284676cf:876:18)
>       at $.(/owncloud/index.php/apps/files/anonymous function).(anonymous function)._onFail
>   (http://demo1.dominio.com/owncloud/core/vendor/jquery-ui/ui/jquery-ui.custom.js?v=a9e1a600d8a15933c86dcad2284676cf:405:25)
>       at Object. (jquery.fileupload.js?v=a9e1a600d8a15933c86dcad2284676cf:910)
>       at j (jquery.js:3099)
>       at Object.fireWith [as rejectWith] (jquery.js:3211)
>       at x (jquery.js:8266)
>       at XMLHttpRequest. (jquery.js:8605)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bueno despues de invenstigar, ya que de esto hay muy poca informacion encontre lo siguiente, el problema esta en el .htaccess y habia que agregar la siguiente linea:

```
AllowOverride All
```

Esto es todo, espero que si alguien mas tiene ese problema lo pueda solucionar con esto, saludos.

Comment: y por que esa línea lo soluciona que significa?

Comment: Permite escribir en el directorio ya que de lo contrario no se pueden cargar archivos.

Comment: Antes estaba esta linea, cuando se dio el problema: {deny from all}

Comment: Esa linea donde se agrega en especifico?